# How can I merge multiple sheets of an excel with same columns and some equal data in row

Tags: r, xlsx

I have an excel file that has 4 sheets with the same columns.  there is an important point, Some row has equal data. For instance. Same Email and Name for each person. 
How can I merge these multiple sheets of this excel with consideration in the same row?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and also read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Stack Overflow is not a free script writing service. Your own research and code attempts are expected. Edit the question to include your code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: Hi, do you have any example to share? Are the colum names the same? We need more informations to give you the proper answer.